# Show hide div element onselect option

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

Here is options (option1 and option2). If option1 is selected, the `<div id="aa">` and `<div id="bb">` should be showed and on selecting option2, `<div id="bb">` and `<div id="cc">` should be showed. how to do it using javascript?

```
<select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>

<div id="aa">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 1</td></tr>
</table></div>

<div id="bb">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 2</td></tr>
</table></div>


<div id="cc">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 3</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

Comment: Again. THIS IS NOT A PEOPLE WILL CODE FOR YOU SITE. LEARN JAVASCRIPT YOURSELF.

Comment: <option onclick="Show('aa');Show('bb');Hide('cc');">option1</option>
i used the above in options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call a function on **onChange event** like

```
 <select onchange="ShowDiv(this.value)"> 
       <option value="1">option1</option>
       <option value="2">option2</option>
 </select>
```

Then in Javascript

```
 <script type="textt/javascript">
      function ShowDiv(val)
      {
           switch(val)
           {
                case 1:
                {
                     document.getElementbyId('aa').style.display = "block";
                     document.getElementbyId('bb').style.display = "block";
                     document.getElementbyId('cc').style.display = "none";
                     break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                     document.getElementbyId('bb').style.display = "block";
                     document.getElementbyId('cc').style.display = "block";
                     document.getElementbyId('aa').style.display = "none";
                     break;
                }
           }
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use id for the select tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#select').change(function(){

     if($(this).val()=="option1") {
        $("#aa").show();
        $("#cc").hide();
     }
     else {
        $("#aa").hide();
        $("#cc").show();
     }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this using javascript:**

```
<select onchange="sample(this.value);">
<option value="op1">option1</option>
<option value="op2">option2</option>
</select>

<div id="aa">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center; display:none;">
<tr><td>Table 1</td></tr>
</table></div>

<div id="bb">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center; display:none;">
<tr><td>Table 2</td></tr>
</table></div>


<div id="cc">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center; displaty:none;">
<tr><td>Table 3</td></tr>
</table></div>

<script>
function sample(value)
{
  if(value=="op1")
{

       document.getElementById('cc').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('aa').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('bb').style.display = 'block';

}
else
{  
       document.getElementById('aa').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('bb').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('cc').style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("select").change(function(){

if($(this).text()=="option1")
{
  $("#aa").show();
 $("#cc").hide();
}
else
{
 $("#aa").hide();
 $("#cc").show();
}
});

})

<select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>

<div id="aa">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 1</td></tr>
</table></div>

<div id="bb">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 2</td></tr>
</table></div>


<div id="cc" style="display:none;">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
<tr><td>Table 3</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

and without Jquery ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        var m_LastDiv = null;
        function SelectChanged(obj) {
            if (m_LastDiv) {
                m_LastDiv.style.display = 'none';
            }
            m_LastDiv = document.getElementById('div' + obj.value)
            if (m_LastDiv) {
                m_LastDiv.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <select onchange='SelectChanged(this);'>
            <option value=''> Hide </option>
            <option value='1'> Show Option 1 </option>
            <option value='2'> Show Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div id='div1' style='display:none;'> Data in div 1 </div>
        <div id='div2' style='display:none;'> Data in div 2</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery** for this

**1.) Include jquery in your `<head>`**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

**Then,**

**HTML**

```
<select id="selBox">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
</select>

<div id="aa" class="hide">
   <table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
   <tr><td>Table 1</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>

<div id="bb" class="hide">
    <table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr><td>Table 2</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div id="cc" class="hide">
   <table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
   <tr><td>Table 3</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {

    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#selBox").on('change', function(){
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if(selVal==1){
        $("#aa, #bb").show();
        $("#cc").hide();
    }else if(selVal==2){
        $("#bb, #cc").show();
        $("#aa").hide();
    }
})
```